# How to panic! in production

Tags: error-handling, rust

`Panic!` seems to be the right way to stop a program while in development mode. But one should not ship a program that displays such a message for an excepted error:

```
thread '<main>' panicked at 'error message: ()', x.rs:785
```

Is there any way to exit a program early with an error code, without displaying developer oriented text? I could use `process::exit` but I've read that it does not perform cleanup, so what should we use?

Comment: Please consult an article about [error handling in rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html). For an advanced read about error handling you might consider reading [this article](http://joeduffyblog.com/2016/02/07/the-error-model/) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`panic!` is not the right way to stop a program.

Its sole purpose is to abort when everything is about to go south and you have no way to recover. If you are expecting some wrong behaviour anywhere, use `Result` and recover from that behaviour by printing a nice message and cleanly exiting.

If you have `panic!`s or `assert!`ions in your code and they trigger, the message you showed is the only correct thing that should be displayed, because it's a bug in your code and there's no clean way to recover from a bug.

Note that `panic!` does not necessarily perform cleanup. If you panic, and another panic happens in a `Drop` impl, the program simply aborts. Also there's a setting for rustc that turns off the cleanup on panic and simply aborts on the `panic!`.

Comment: Thanks! "cleanly exiting" -> that's my problem. I have read that `process::exit` is not "clean"

Comment: `process::exit` is not less "clean" than `panic!`. It's just guaranteed not to try to run cleanup code, while `panic!` might try to run destructors depending on your setup

Comment: Just to clarify: the only way I'm aware of to "cleanly" exit a Rust program is to make said exit *an explicit part of your code*.  There is *no* magic "shut everything down cleanly" wand to wave.  One thing you *could* try is having cleanup logic in a separate "monitor" process, but again, that's something you have to explicitly write yourself.